# How get the attribute value of XML node depending on another attribute value in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dom

Here is the XML:

```
     <MatML_Doc>
        <Material>
           <BulkDetails>
               <Name>ABS</Name>
               <Class> <Name>PLASTIC</Name></Class>
               <Subclass> <Name>ABS Polymer</Name></Subclass>
               <PropertyData property="Material_Type">
                   <Data format="string">IsotropicMaterial</Data>
               </PropertyData>
               <PropertyData property="Version">
                   <Data format="string">4.0</Data>
               </PropertyData>
               <PropertyData property="Category">
                   <Data format="string">PLASTIC</Data>
               </PropertyData>      
               <PropertyData property="CoatingsStudioMaterialName">
                 <Data format="string">ABS Plastic</Data>
               </PropertyData>
               <PropertyData property="CoatingsVisualizationColor">
                 <Data format="exponential">168, 168, 168</Data>
               </PropertyData>
               <PropertyData property="ColorID">
                 <Data format="integer">87</Data>
               </PropertyData>
           </BulkDetails>
        </Material>
   <MatML_Doc>
```

I want to get the value of the data property "ColorID" (i want the number 87) if the value of the node "Name" is ABS.
What is the usual procedure?

**I add my Solution here:**

```
private static int GetColorIdInXmlByMaterial(string material, XmlDocument doc)
 {
    XmlElement element = doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = element.SelectNodes("//BulkDetails");

    foreach(XmlNode node in xmlNodeList)
    {
        if (node["Name"].InnerText.Equals(material))
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(node["ColorID"].InnerText);
        }
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: First get the Name then check if it is "ABS" you can get the Color ID.

Answer (score 1):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Material> meterials = doc.Descendants("Material").Select(x => new Material()
            {
                name = (string)x.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault(),
                className = (string)x.Descendants("Class").FirstOrDefault().Element("Name"),
                properties = x.Descendants("PropertyData").Select(y => new Property()
                {
                    property = (string)y.Attribute("property"),
                    format = (string)y.Element("Data").Attribute("format"),
                    value = (string)y.Element("Data")
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();

            Dictionary<string, Material> dict = materials.GroupBy(x => x.name, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            Material lookup = dict["ABS"];
        }
    }
    public class Material
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string className { get; set; }
        public List<Property> properties { get; set; }
    }
    public class Property
    {
        public string property { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My xml file have over 10k Lines. 
I have read xml linq has a poor performance when working with large data. Whats about that? :)

Comment: No.  Xml Serialization has poor performance.  Linq is much faster.  I added a dictionary to the code.  Linq can be slow when reading from a database under certain conditions and can be slow if exceeds the memory of the machine.

Comment: Is there a advantage compared to my solution? because i find it much more difficult to understand the linq solution

Comment: XmlDocument is an old version of the Net Xml library and XDocument is the new version of the Net Library.  XmlDocument is much more complicated and takes more lines of code.  I find XmlDocument is much harder to work with than XDocument.